# Calculate the constants a and b and then the probability (0.2<X) {see attached picture}

Tags: probability, expected-value, density-function

[image: click here to see question]

I got a = 3/2 and b = 1/4 but how do I do the second part of the question?

Comment: To find a probability from a PDF, you should work out a certain integral. Do you know what it should be?

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Probability is the area under the graph for the corresponding pdf. For this case, the area is a trapezium.

Recall that area of a trapezium is $\frac{h}2(a+b)$